# Не собирается элементарное приложение Android Studio

Tags: android

```
package myapplication.prof_ege.com.myapplication4;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText chisloTextView;
    TextView rezultEditText;
    Button NMM;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText chisloTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chisloTextView);
        TextView rezultEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultEditText);
        Button NMM;
        NMM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NMM);
        NMM.setOnClickListener(Cliker);}

    private void calculate() {
        String k = chisloTextView.getText().toString();
        int m = Integer.parseInt(k);
        int n = m + 1;
        rezultEditText.setText(Integer.toString(n));
    }

    OnClickListener Cliker = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            calculate();
        }
    };

}
```

Теперь В event log пишет

```
Emulator: coreaudio: Could not lock voice for audioOutputDeviceIOProc

Emulator: Reason: Invalid argument
```

Следуя советам в сети, я изменил в `config.ini   hw.audioInput=yes` на  `hw.audioInput=no`, но не помогло

При запуске эмулятора
My Application has stopped
Open app again...

Запустил apk-файл в телефоне. Тоже не пошел.Выдает следующее:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapplication.prof_ege.com.myapplication4/myapplication.prof_ege.com.myapplication4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at myapplication.prof_ege.com.myapplication4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6864)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
```

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapplication.prof_ege.com.myapplication4.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Оно компилится, собирается и даже запускается. Но падает в процессе выполнения. Почему - смотрите в логах. Если не станет ясна ошибка - выложите лог в вопрос текстом, указав на какой строке ошибка.

Comment: ***chisloTextView*** Нужно использовать понятные названия для переменных.

Comment: Так у вас в разметке ничего нет, конечно оно не собирается. В разметке должен быть TextView, EditText, Button. И каждый должен иметь id, по котрому его можно найти. Я не советую вам так заниматься андроидом. Начните читать книгу по нему. Например, android. Программирование для профессионалов. Там на первых же страницах это объяснено. Прочтя книгу, вы с такими базовыми проблемами никогда не столкнетесь.

Comment: Точно, ну я дебил - надо же сначала было с этим разобраться

Comment: Спасибо, указали ориентир. С наступающим!

Answer (score 4):

А почему переменная `rezultEditText` имеет тип `TextView`?
Я подозреваю, что `rezultEditText` должно быть `TextView`, а `chisloTextView` должно быть `EditText`.

И вы объявляете две глобальные переменные

```
TextView chisloTextView

TextView rezultEditText
```

А в `onCreate` снова объявляете те же переменные, только локальные и их инициализируете. А потом в методе `calculate` обращаетесь к глобальным переменным, но они не проинициализированны.

---

Судя по логам у вас `NullPointerException` на обработчике кнопки.
Удалите из `onCreate` объявление новых переменных и проинициализируйте там глобальные, т.е. `onCreate` должен выглядить так

```
Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   chisloTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chisloTextView);
   rezultEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultEditText);
   NMM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NMM);
   NMM.setOnClickListener(Cliker);
}
```

И выложите код activity_main.xml, там ошибка скорее всего.

Comment: Спасибо, я изменил тип переменной, но результат тот же самый - отрицательный

Comment: Обновите код в посте и выложите код разметки.

Comment: Обновил код и добавил информацию из event log